# Can't push object to array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this simple code

```
let pathFinder = (entranceX, entranceY, grid) => {
            let distanceFromTop = entranceX;
            let distanceFromLeft = entranceY;

            let location = {
                distanceFromTop: distanceFromTop,
                distanceFromLeft: distanceFromLeft,
                path: [],
                status: 'Start'
            }


            console.log('start', location)

            let queue = [];
            queue.push(location);
            console.log('queue', queue)
}
```

And I made sure that "location" is not empty, it shows just fine in the console as:

"start {distanceFromTop: 1, distanceFromLeft: 0, path: Array(0), status: "Start"}"

but when I want to add it to the queue I end up with something that doesnt look like an empty array, but the length is 0

"queue [{…}] 
length :0"

Am i missing something obvious? Tried to add it via queue[location] but it also didnt work

Comment: tested it and seemed fine. sure you're executing it i mean you are just setting the queue varible within that scope and you're not returning it

Comment: How are you calling this function?

Comment: can you give us abit more informarion on how you're exicuting and what where you're trying to access queue.

Comment: I execute the function by button click. Then queue is used to store more locations in pathdinging algorythm. However, the queue I pass to next functions is basically empty even though it shouldnt

Comment: **@MazMat**, can you please change all of **let** keywords to **var** and try. Your code is not working when I tested it on http://rextester.com/l/nodejs_online_compiler. When I changed all **let** to **var** it worked fine. I got `start { distanceFromTop: 23,
  distanceFromLeft: 56,
  path: [],
  status: 'Start' }
queue [ { distanceFromTop: 23,
    distanceFromLeft: 56,
    path: [],
    status: 'Start' } ]` as result.

Comment: Nothing changed in my case (in VSC). Im just completely lost, dont know whats happening

Answer (score 1):

You should check up on the difference between let and var

```
var pathFinder = (entranceX, entranceY, grid) => {
        var distanceFromTop = entranceX;
        var distanceFromLeft = entranceY;

        let location = {
            distanceFromTop: distanceFromTop,
            distanceFromLeft: distanceFromLeft,
            path: [],
            status: 'Start'
        }


        console.log('start', location)

        var queue = [];
        queue.push(location);
        console.log('queue', queue)
}
```

Let can only be used in the scope block in which it’s declared where as var is throughout the function it is declared or globally. Changing the first three (the function and the two distance as well as the queue) variables to var should fix this for you. If not changing them all definitely would.

Comment: Changed everything in my code to var. No changes to how it behaves. Does it matter that I use react with this? Probably shouldnt, but im completely lost now

Comment: It may be when your passing variables. When I test it on a native JavaScript compiler and run the function manually. It works as expected. Maybe post more of your code and we may be able to help. There may be an error elsewhere in your code. - also to reference the array I used queue[0] not queue[location]

Comment: I will prepare the codepen instance for that, because I have 2 files.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/zkz3l2oxy3   Relevant code is in maze.js in findTest() function. There might be a bit of a mess since I was trying a lot of different things out before I tried this pathfinding algorythm. The grid doesnt seem to be rendering correctly in the sandbox, but other than that everything is like on my machine. Exactly same conosle output too

Comment: @MazMat findTest is never actually ran in the code you provided. Could this be the reason why??

Comment: You have to click the button on the bottom of the page to make it run :)

Comment: Well I can guarantee it’s not empty as if you do console.log(queue[0]) it gives you an output ☺️ as I stated above though.

Comment: Im unsure why it’s not logging the whole object but when I do a queue.length it’s definitely there and shows 1 as expected. I don’t believe this lack of output will cause any issues for you. I hope that helps

Comment: Well, at least now I can focus on other bugs, because I was sure it's this one that prevents me from having a solution. Turns out it was just some logging issue. Don't know why it happened, but thanks for the help, ypu probalby saved me a lot of time fixing something that isnt broken, Thank you

Comment: Omg I am so sorry. It’s possibly because it has deep nesting. Use console.log(JSON.stringify(queue));  you’ll get an output

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the push is working but the array is not being displayed while logging 
 the whole object

```
queue.push(location);
console.log("queue", queue[0]);
```

*queue {distanceFromTop: 1, distanceFromLeft: 1, path: Array(0), status: "Start"}*

And if you change the console as,

```
console.log("queue", Array.from(queue));
```

You can see the contents of the array too.

Comment: Huh, Youre right, but why would that be this way? I never had such problems with displaying huge arrays of objects.

Comment: console.log("queue", Array.from(queue)); to see all the contents of the array